automatic log-out even though all suspend/hibernate/sleep/hybrid-sleep/lid-lock switched off
I run a media server that should never log-out, sleep, suspend, hibernate, reboot, or power off unless I tell it to. Since fresh install of 24.04 Desktop, any time I leave the machine alone or power off the monitor, I come back to a logged out session. This shuts down all running processes.
Sleep, suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep, lid-lock (even though desktop), screen dim all switched off as user. Running sudo gnome-control-center reveals root settings are 24.04 defaults. The settings GUI toggles will not let me switch the setting off (toggle resets instantly).
Terminal reports "failed to launch: dbus"
I've been running Ubuntu this way since version 14 with no issues.
I want to prevent shutting down processes and logging out. Is the fact that I can't change the root settings for Power and Security a part of the problem?
Version: Desktop 24.04
Power setting: Performance

You may want to report this as a bug. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

A long shot but your description has some characteristics of
Swap (Memory really?) leak on fresh(ish) install of 24.04
In this case as memory fills up things start to slow down and eventually the Gnome graphic interfaces logs out and resets everything. (One time it actually crashed the OS such that I had to re-install it.)
I have a notion from your description that you may have installed 24.04 with a legacy /Home which would be similar to me.
For it to be this I would expect your legacy Desktop icons to be absent in 24.04. (You can also use free to monitor your memory usage. Very roughly the leak increases memory usage by 200M/90s.)
To fix you can turn off the desktop Gnome addon and/or move all your icons from your desktop from a terminal and then add them one-by-one and if they graphically show up keep them and if they seem to wipe them all off then take them off again. See link, above, for more details. (Ubuntu bug #2067802 raised.)
